# How can I define transition when I click a picture to changepage?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I use $.mobile.changePage('#login', 'fade'); but I still get a silde tansition

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#login', {transition: 'fade'});
```

or:

```
$.mobile.changePage($('#login'), {transition: 'fade'});
```

The first parameter is a url or jQuery element, the second parameter `options` is an object hashmap (you can put many options in it using JSON notation).

See this page for all the options, the 'Examples' section shows how to pass in multiple options:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html